# Assembly has no strong name though i added dll in advanced Package mode

Tags: 2010, assembly-references

I want to user Twitterizer for posting Status Updates through a WPF-Form. Since i need  the Twitterizer2.dll to do this i first included it and then added it to the package using the advanced package mode.

Im still getting the Error that says "Assembly has no strong name" - i checked the properties for the project and the "key.snk" is used to sign the assembly..

Any Ideas why Error still comes up?!

Comment: Did you tried to delete and recreate key.snk?

Comment: Same Error occurs, doesn't change a thing :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps because Twitterizer2.dll (rather than your project output) does not have a strong name? If this is the case, and you can get your hands on the source code, then you should load the Twitterizer project, sign it and build your own version of it.

Comment: Can't imagine that, because Twitterizer is commonly used and there would be some remarks about it.. gonna try it anyway!

Comment: rebuilt it with the source, now its functional! thank you very much!